# Is there a way to see a name in the url on my pc instead of ip address

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, hostname

I have an app that serves up http webpages.  It runs on my pc as a service  and is accessed by using either our outsideip:port or on my pc: 127.0.0.1:1988.  The outside ip and port are forward in our router to my pc.

currently I have an outside .org that is forwarded to our outsideip:port and it starts the app.  What I want to to change is instead of seeing http:/114.111.888.45:1988 in the browser I'd like to see a name or .com. Something other than the ip and port.

I'm hoping it can be done.  I'm running Win10Pro.  The app has been running on this PC for 3 years as a service.

Thank You,

Ed

Comment: How is the .org forwarding to your IP? Is it redirecting or is there an actual DNS record that points to the external IP?

Comment: I second shawn's point. You need a type A DNS record pointing to your dynamic public IP, which you can obtain through services like FreeDNS, DynDNS, or the like. It sounds like you are using a DNS forwarding service which loads up somebody else's website. That website then redirects the user's browser to your IP:port. Internally, you need to edit your router's static DNS entries to return the IP of your machine via a name/domain of your choice. Not every router has that feature.

Comment: Use may use the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to give a name to an IP address.

Comment: I purchased a url from GoDaddy and have it foward to our external ip and port.

Comment: As a test I changed the hosts file to test running internally. We can start the app running http://127.0.0.1:8888 .  So I modified the hosts file with 127.0.0.1 myapp   now internally I can do http://myapp:8888 and it works but how would this work from the outside?  I'm confused.  Appreciate your help.  This has been a thorn in my side.